How to Implement Drag-and-Drop with MudBlazor in a MudTable
I'm trying to implement drag-and-drop functionality in a Blazor application using MudBlazor. I aim to have a single drop zone containing a table (MudTable) displaying a student list. I've tried several approaches but need help getting the drag-and-drop to work correctly. Here are the details of my current implementation and the issues I've encountered.
Current Implementation
I started with the following code:
@page "/main"
@using MudBlazor

<MudPaper Class="ma-4 flex-grow-1">
    <MudDropContainer T="Student" Items="_students" ItemDropped="ItemUpdated" Class="d-flex flex-column mud-height-full">
        <ChildContent>
            <MudDropZone T="Student" Identifier="singleDropZone" Class="flex-grow-1" AllowReorder="true">
                <MudTable Items="_students">
                    <HeaderContent>
                        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
                        <MudTh>Age</MudTh>
                        <MudTh>Degree</MudTh>
                        <MudTh>College</MudTh>
                    </HeaderContent>
                    <RowTemplate>
                        <MudTr>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Age">@context.Age</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Degree">@context.Degree</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="College">@context.College</MudTd>
                        </MudTr>
                    </RowTemplate>
                </MudTable>
            </MudDropZone>
        </ChildContent>
        <ItemRenderer>
            <MudListItem>
                <MudTextField Value="@context.Name" Label="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
                <MudTextField Value="@context.Age.ToString()" Label="Age" ReadOnly="true" />
                <MudTextField Value="@context.Degree" Label="Degree" ReadOnly="true" />
                <MudTextField Value="@context.College" Label="College" ReadOnly="true" />
            </MudListItem>
        </ItemRenderer>
    </MudDropContainer>
</MudPaper>

@code {
    private void ItemUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<Student> dropItem)
    {
        // Remove the item from the old position
        _students.Remove(dropItem.Item);
        
        // Insert the item at the new position
        _students.Insert(dropItem.Index, dropItem.Item);
    }

    private List<Student> _students = new()
    {
        new Student { Name = "John Doe", Age = 20, Degree = "B.Sc", College = "College A" },
        new Student { Name = "Jane Smith", Age = 22, Degree = "B.A", College = "College B" },
        new Student { Name = "Alice Johnson", Age = 21, Degree = "B.Com", College = "College C" },
        new Student { Name = "Bob Brown", Age = 23, Degree = "B.Tech", College = "College D" },
        new Student { Name = "Charlie Green", Age = 24, Degree = "B.Arch", College = "College E" }
    };

    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Degree { get; set; }
        public string College { get; set; }
    }
}


Issues Encountered
The MudItemDropInfo does not contain an Index property, which caused compilation errors.
I've tried other methods of handling the reordering, but they haven't worked correctly.
Alternative Attempts
Attempt 1
I removed the Index property handling and tried to reorder the list without it:
private void ItemUpdated(MudItemDropInfo<Student> dropItem)
{
    // Attempted to reorder without index
    var item = dropItem.Item;
    _students.Remove(item);
    // Logic to insert at new position needed
}


Attempt 2
I wrapped the table rows in a drop zone, but drag-and-drop still didn't work as expected:
<MudDropZone T="Student" Identifier="singleDropZone" Class="flex-grow-1" AllowReorder="true">
    <MudTable Items="_students">
        <RowTemplate>
            <MudTr>
                <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
                <MudTd DataLabel="Age">@context.Age</MudTd>
                <MudTd DataLabel="Degree">@context.Degree</MudTd>
                <MudTd DataLabel="College">@context.College</MudTd>
            </MudTr>
        </RowTemplate>
    </MudTable>
</MudDropZone>


Requirements
A single drop zone containing a table.
Ability to drag and drop rows within the table to reorder them.
Question
How can I correctly implement drag-and-drop functionality for a table using MudBlazor? Any guidance or working examples would be greatly appreciated!

If using simpleTables would be fine aswell, you could try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75301431/mudblazor-table-draggable-rows
